# How do I add a texture to a cube that already has one

Tags: texturing

So I am making a kar98k model but the entire texture is metal everytime I switch to Texture Paint the whole model gets turned into the wooden texture but for the bolt and barrel I intend to be a metal texture so far I have everything finished I just need to know how to add a specific texture to my bolt and barrel.

Comment: I voted down because in my opinion this question does not show any research effort. I do not mean disrespect, however it is very basic functionality of Blender that you are asking about. It might be more logical as well as faster for yourself to watch some tutorials first and read about the basic functions in the documentation. You will get more detailed information a lot faster this way as it is already very well documented. You can read about assigning different materials here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/assigning_a_material.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this? If so, you need 2 materials for 1 object.

[image: 2 Textures]

I think you've already known how to insert the texture. Select the face that you want to give texture, use the unwrap method in edit mode, select second material and you need to press assign. Hope this help!

[image]

Comment: @Trenches_Modeler Don't post thank you as a comment. Instead mark the answer as accepted, or at least upvote it.